# addtarget on Facebook (standard) login button

Tags: ios, facebook

This regards the STANDARD Facebook login button, not the custom one.

Im wondering if its not possible to use some delegate method or callback in response to a successful Facebook-login. Im basically trying to present a new view controller after returning to the app (from browser Facebook). First I tried adding a selector to the login button, but the selector is never called on click, so for some reason I think this is only allowed when creating a custom Facebook login.. I did create a custom, but it just seems overkill for what I'm trying to do (plus I have to manually handle logged in /loggedout). Isn't there some way to respond to login success on the default Facebook button?

Comment: are you using FBSDK ? If you are using FBSDK, check for FBSDKAppEventNameFBSessionAuthEnd flag

Comment: @Mr.T I am using FBSDKLogin and some others, but not FBSDK as a single(maybe thats why I don't see the flag popup in Xcode?). Searching for that flag on google resulted in very few results. Should I then add an observer for that flag? I normally would expect some completion block or delegate method that is invoked on return. .

Comment: Im a fool.. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate